# How to install an old version of OpenBSD inside VirtualBox?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, openbsd

I'm reading an old Phrack article and I would like to install OpenBSD 3.0 inside VirtualBox.  I remember installing this very version using actual physical floppy disks in 2001, but nowadays I don't feel like dedicating one physical machine to it.

So how do you boot using `cdrom30.fs` with VirtualBox ?

`file cdrom30.fs` outputs:

cdrom30.fs: Unix Fast File system [v1] (little-endian), last mounted on /mnt, last written at Thu Oct 18 22:54:56 2001, clean flag 1, number of blocks 5760, number of data blocks 5695, number of cylinder groups 1, block size 4096, fragment size 512, minimum percentage of free blocks 0, rotational delay 0ms, disk rotational speed 5rps, SPACE optimization

How to make a bootable ISO CDROM image of this file ? 
Any other solution, like a network installation, would be acceptable. I just need to know how to have a clean install of OpenBSD 3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtualbox will have no trouble reading that as-is:

- just **Rename** `cdrom30.fs` to `cdrom30.iso` *(virtualbox will error without this)*
- open **Settings -> Storage**
- use the Icons below the tree to **Add New Storage Controller**
- if not asked, click **Add Floppy Device** on the floppy controller tree entry
- select your ISO (cdrom30.fs). Boot, walla!

Downloaded `cdrom30.fs` this morning to confirm, booted right up! Ah nostalgia

Comment: i'm assuming the article is "Stack Smashing for Fun and Profit"? For those interested: http://phrack.org/issues/60/6.html  I think i'll be reading that later tonight!

Comment: I think you meant 'Smashing The Kernel Stack For Fun And Profit'.. which is possibly an allusion to Aleph One's Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit (1996). And yes that's the one I'm reading.

Comment: yes, i was typing lazy :/  but i was unaware of the original reference, neat!

Comment: Just wanted to add that the default network card did not work for me. This one works: Intel Pro 1000/T Server. It's downloading base30.tgz right now.